# Android 8 nullpointer exception with function call in fragment (only on certain devices!!!)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-8.0-oreo

I currently see a very strange nullpointer-exception that I can not explain myself.

I have an Activity which hosts two fragments. 
The context-menu is evaluated in the host-activity and then calls a public function in one of the fragments.

While this works well for several phones with android 7 I usually get a nullpointer-exception on my Samsung S7 with Android 8. 
The nullpointer-exception occurs when I try to access any UI-elements of the fragment within this function call!

I already checked that the fragment instances are valid, and they are ok. They are fully initialized and added on the onCreate of the host. 
Whenever I trigger the function from inside the fragment it is ok, but not if I call the same function from the context menu of the hosting activity!

At first it looks like a timing problem, because sometimes it works, although relativ seldom. 
What is the reason of this behaviour and how can I get over this strange error?

Thanks
Andreas

```
public class EpaperFragmentHost extends AppCompatActivity 
{
private CustomViewPager mViewPager;
private Toolbar toolbar;

private EpaperPicture_Fragment EpaperPictureFrag;
private int Picture_Fragment_Position = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connectfragmenthost);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle( String.format( Locale.GERMAN, 
    getString(R.string.Connectingto_STRING) , mDeviceName) );
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new Connection_fragment_adapter( 
    getSupportFragmentManager() );
    EpaperPictureFrag = EpaperPicture_Fragment.newInstance( );
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.setFragment( Picture_Fragment_Position, 
    EpaperPictureFrag );

    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.epapermenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.menuitem_savepicture:
            // This call will fail on some phones, but works on others! 
            // And not because EpaperPictureFrag would be null, but the 
            // myDrawView inside this instance is null!
            EpaperPictureFrag.takeScreenshot( true);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    boolean result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return result;
}


}
```

and this is the fragment:

```
public class EpaperPicture_Fragment extends Fragment 
{
    public DrawView myDrawView;

    public EpaperPicture_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

public static EpaperPicture_Fragment newInstance(  ) {
    EpaperPicture_Fragment fragment = new EpaperPicture_Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_epaper_picture, container, 
    false);

    btn_Clear = v.findViewById(R.id.clear_btn);
    btn_addText = v.findViewById(R.id.addtext_btn);
    btn_Transmit = v.findViewById(R.id.transmit_btn);
    myDrawView = v.findViewById(R.id.epaper);

    btn_Clear.setOnClickListener( this );
    btn_addText.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_Transmit.setOnClickListener( this );

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch( v.getId() ){

        case R.id.transmit_btn:
            // This call works! 
            takeScreenshot( true );                
            break;        
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public File takeScreenshot(boolean showToast) {

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC SECTION! 
    // Why can myDrawView be null, if the fragment exists? 
    myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap cachedBitmap = myDrawView.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap copyBitmap = cachedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    myDrawView.destroyDrawingCache();
    // ...
}
}
```

Comment: It seems you are doing something outside of the specified behavior. Post some code to get better help, we can only guess at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is:

I changed the check for storage access in the base-class to a new mode.

And this check caused each activity which was inherited by the baseclass to re-create after checking the access rights! 
I found it by generating all overwrite methods of the base class and made a log-output in each. It was a terrible destroy and create-sequence.

Unfortunately I changed my test-phone around the same time...